# re connect client to server after closing

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-2.7

I'm using a code witch permits only 4 connection on 4 different ports.
This code is working but when a client is closing the connection, it can't re-establish connection. Connection is refused. Think it is because the thread is closed. How to solve this ?
I can't change the ports number...

```
enter code here
```

## -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

from socket import *

BUFF = 25

def server(host, port):

```
def response(key):
    return 'Server response: ' + key

def handler(clientsock,addr):
    while 1:
        data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
        if not data: break
        print repr(addr) + ' recv:' + repr(data)
        clientsock.send(response(data))
        print repr(addr) + ' sent:' + repr(response(data))
        if "close" == data.rstrip(): break # type 'close' on client console to close connection from the server side

    clientsock.close()
    print addr, "- closed connection" #log on console


addr = (host, port)
serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serversock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind(addr)
serversock.listen(1)
clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
handler(clientsock, addr)
```

if **name**=='**main**':
    import threading

```
HOST = '192.168.0.12'
PORTS = [10001,10002,10003,10004]
threads = []
for port in PORTS:
    th = threading.Thread(target=server, args=(HOST, port))
    th.start()
    threads.append(th)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Python, but I will give it a shot.

In your thread, you probably need add a loop to accept new connections.  serversock.accept() and the call "handler" would be in that loop.  That should allow a client to again connect to the server when a client closes a connection.

Here is how I suspect it should look (no including error checking and with no knowledge of Python):

```
while  1: 
     clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
     handler(clientsock,addr);
```